# Where has the "Remote Systems" view gone, or is there an equivalent?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

In Eclipse with CDT, version "Oxygen", one used to be able to go in the menu: Window / Show View / Others..., then there was a Folder "Remote Systems" containing an item again called "Remote Systems".
You could set this up to view files in a remote target file system from within a window in Eclipse.

I tried this now with the current Eclipse 10.4 (aka "2021-9"), as gotten from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-09/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers). The whole "Remote Systems" folder is gone and entering "remote" in the search textbox  on the Window / Show View / Other dialog yields no results.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the newest thing about the topic I found is [this](https://javabeginnerstutorial.com/eclipse-2/how-to-connect-to-remote-system-using-eclipse-ide/), but that Remote System Explorer is also absent from my Eclipse-CDT installation under Perspectives.

Has this been renamed, or replaced by something different? Is this functionality still part of Eclipse-CDT?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, apparently it used to come installed by default with the CDT installers I used in the past, but it's not currently.
Under **Help / Install New Software...**, I entered "Remote Systems" in the search, installed the "**Remote Systems Exlporer End User Runtime**" that popped up.
Now it is there.

Comment: The [_Remote System Explorer_ can also be found on the Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remote-system-explorer-ssh-telnet-ftp-and-dstore-protocols). If you think it should be included in a specific Eclipse IDE package by default, you might [report it to the _Eclipse Packaging Project_ (EPP)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: @howlger "Remote System Explorer" is not available on latest eclipse versions. At least it is not supported on 2022.9. I#ve installed at first from market place, didn't helped. But it works, when "Install New Software".